# Android device detected by mtp-detect but not by adb

Tags: android, mtp

I'm running Kubuntu 12.04 and connecting it via USB to an LG P705 Android device.  A short time ago the *adb devices* command listed it -- but something happened and now that command now gives only an empty list.  Yet *mtp-detect* finds and lists the device correctly.  What might have happened?

Answer (score 0):

For adb you have to install android-tools package.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb
```

and if you wants the fastboot:

```
sudo apt-get install android-tools-fastboot
```